# Oracle GROUP BY clause is having issue

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

SQL Query in oracle database is:

```
SELECT max(employee_id)
from bank_data
group by job_type
having job in ('Engineer','Artist');
```

My table data is:

[image: table data]

I get below error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 65
```

The explanation of this exception says when query doesn't contain all expression, but why should I include extra things if I don't want it?

Comment: The `HAVING` clause is intended for set function conditions. Use `WHERE` instead for regular column conditions.

Comment: You should add sample table data and _the expected result_ to the question - as formatted text, no images.

Comment: What are you trying to refer by 'the set function condition'? What are they?

Comment: Set based conditions, e.g. `having count(*) > 1`.

Answer (score 1):

HAVING behaves like a where clause that is done after the group by is performed. Just like you can only select columns/expressions that have been grouped on, you can only HAVING something that appears in the group by, or is the result of an aggregate function

In essence your original query conceptually could be written like this:

```
select * from
(
  select job_type, max(employee_id) as maxid 
  from bank_data
  group by job_type
) x
where job in ('Engineer','Artist') --job doesn't exist here
```

It's not exactly the same as a HAVING but it will work to explain the key concept here: because you don't group on job, you cannot use it in the HAVING (because the subquery doesn't SELECT job, the outer query cannot use it in the WHERE).

As jarlh indicates you probably just want to use a where clause. I recommend you also select the job type, because otherwise you'll get two result rows and not know which employee id is the max for which job type

```
select job_type, max(employee_id) as maxid 
from bank_data
where job in ('Engineer','Artist')
group by job_type;
```

Edit: after your comments:

```
select max(employee_id) as maxid 
from bank_data
where job in ('Engineer','Artist')
group by job;
```

Without using group by/with putting the numbers on the same row :

```
select max(a.employee_id) as maxengid, max(b.employee_id) as maxartistid 
from 
  (select * from bank_data where job in ('Engineer')) a 
  cross join bank_data b
  (select * from bank_data where job in ('Artist')) b
```

Or

```
select
  max(case when job = 'Engineer' then employee_id end) as maxengid,
  max(case when job = 'Artist' then employee_id end) as maxartgid 
from bank_data
where job in ('Engineer','Artist');
```

Comment: I want to avoid job_type in my resultset.

Comment: Ok, so take it out of the select, then

Comment: Also I want to display max employee_id in both the professions separately that's why I went ahead with group by clause.

Comment: For the example data you have posted, please indicate the result you are expecting.

Comment: It would be 
453
783

Comment: Can I get that without group by also?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include extra things then don't include.

If you want max(employee id) then use below :

```
    SELECT max(employee_id)
    from bank_data
    where job in ('Engineer','Artist');
```

If you want your result according to job_type. Then use job_type in select columns and use group by job_type.

```
  SELECT max(employee_id) as eid,job_type from bank_data where job in ('Engineer','Artist')
    group by job_type;
```

Refer below urls:

```
'https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp'
'https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp'
'https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp'
```

Comment: I was trying to print the max employee_id of person with job Engineer and the maximum employee_id of person with job artist. Your queries are for getting the maximum employee_id in both these jobs. That's why I was using group by.